# Troubleshooting invalid_client error with custom Oauth connecting to Snowflake

Tags: oauth, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

OAuth for custom client:

> Error while generating access token and refresh token from the authorization endpoint.

When getting access token and refresh token from the authorization end point, I am getting and invalid_client error though all the required parameters are provided. I referred to following [document](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/oauth-custom.html#errors): here it is mentioned that "invalid_client" error would be received when there was a failure relating to client authentication, such as the client being unknown, a client secret mismatch, etc.

I understand a client id and secret mismatch error. But what does "unknown_client" mean? Is it related to a request coming from an invalid host?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this error officially documented, but if I had to venture a guess, I would interpret that error as the client was not found or identified by the client authenticator.

However, seeing as how that's only my personal interpretation, I additionally would troubleshoot the error as if you were receiving an "invalid_client" error.  It seems to be in the same ballpark.